# Asus motherboard with 'CPU_LED' on

Tags: windows-8.1, cpu, motherboard

First, [Here](http://imgur.com/a/yfQBx) are some pictures of what I'm seeing.

---

[Here is by build:](http://ca.pcpartpicker.com/p/DsJCMp)

*CPU* | AMD FX-8320E 3.2GHz 8-Core Processor

*CPU Cooler* | Silverstone AR03 81.4 CFM Sleeve Bearing CPU Cooler

*Motherboard* | Asus M5A99X EVO R2.0 ATX AM3+ Motherboard

*Memory* | Kingston Fury White Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) DDR3-1600 Memory

*Storage* | Samsung 840 EVO 120GB 2.5" Solid State Drive

*Storage* | Seagate Barracuda 2TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive

*Video Card* | Asus GeForce GTX 970 4GB STRIX Video Card

*Case* | NZXT S340 (White) ATX Mid Tower Case

*Power Supply* | SeaSonic 620W 80+ Bronze Certified Fully-Modular ATX Power Supply

*Wireless Network Adapter* | TP-Link TL-WN881ND 802.11b/g/n PCI-E Wi-Fi Adapter

*Case Fan x2* | Corsair Air Series AF140 Quiet Edition 67.8 CFM 140mm  Fan

---

This has been my experience with the computer so far:

I spent about three hours troubleshooting last night trying to find a fix for this. Let's start at the beginning: Tuesday was the day I completed the build upon my 970 arriving. I installed Windows 8.1 with a few minor issues that resulted in the computer working completely fine. The next day I decided that since I got Windows installed, it was time to update the motherboard drivers and then the GPU's. I installed them and once I finished doing all, all needed a reboot to apply, so I shut my computer down since I would be going out for a few hours. I get back to 'turn on' the computer with it's newly installed drivers and it doesn't show any display, and the red CPU_led is lit up - this is the current situation even after trying the following:

- Checked to make sure all the power cables were in place and they hadn't somehow became unplugged, the CPU was - great! I found the issue - nope, still no POST.
- attempted to use the BIOS flashback on the motherboard to reset the BIOS using a USB which contained everything the CD which came my mobo. (Yes, I used the correct USB port). The green light on the 'BIOS_FLBK' behaved as it should - flashed while it was working. During this time the USB was also flashing.
- Restarting using only one stick of RAM installed (on the rightmost slot).
- The 24 and 8 pin connectors are fine and in place.
- Took the cooler off, and the CPU out to check for bent pins (even though it already started fine and there is no way for the pins to bend if it's been installed correctly. There were two which weren't *perfect*, but by no means bent - I fixed them using a mechanical pencil anyway. After that I re-installed the CPU as well as the cooler.
- Tried clearing CMOS.
- When I try to boot, all the fans start up (including the GPU's), you can hear the normal sounds of a computer starting up, and nothing else happens except that red led.

At this point I'm out of ideas as for what to try - I feel I tried everything.

Any and all suggestions/help is greatly appreciated. I don't want to return the motherboard, but I got it from Amazon so if I need to there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: I wouldn't really have consider the pins bent (maybe off max 2 degrees), I was just trying to be as thorough as possible. The CPU had been working fine, I don't know where the issue is because it may be a connection at the motherboard itself (couldn't it?).

I'm pretty sure that the CPU is 95watts (edit-oh, did you meant GPU?.)

For booting without it, do I just take off the cooler, and take out the CPU? At that point should it just go into the BIOS screen?

Comment: My PSU is 620W, how much should it be to handle this?

Comment: Strip it down to just MB, CPU and PSU. Does it beep like it has no RAM and or no video?  Does that CPU LED come on in that scenario?

Comment: the light still comes on when it's just the CPU. 

I don't have a speaker for it right now, but I will pick one up tomorrow.